# What is the best way to check condition before run functions

Tags: javascript

I need to check some conditions before calling functions and those functions are calling from different js files like index.js or app.js.

What will be the best way to check that conditions before calling others? Think about you are doing something like authentication, if user is authenticated then call the function. I need to check that condition for 30 functions.

Instead of making changes on the functions I need to write one function/attribute/whatever and that needs to effect others.

```
file1.js:
function1
function2
function3
...
function30

file2.js:
file1.function1();

file3.js:
file1.function15();
```

Comment: `if` is a good way

Comment: So adding if statement to all 30 functions is the best way? @JaromandaX

Comment: You could wrap your if in a function, and pass in a callback to make things tidier. But to all intents and purposes it's still just an if.

Comment: No magic way to do it without refactoring

Comment: You may use && to short-circuit the statement. Like, `condition && fun()` , fun() will be called only when conditon is true.

Comment: @charlietfl how can I refactor it? Any source or idea would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an example of my suggestion in the comments, this is a simple way to wrap each function with an auth check without adding too much clutter to your calls.

```js
// Some mock up of you existing code
var authenticated = true;

function thing1() { alert(1); }
function thing2() { alert(2); }
function thing3() { alert(3); }

// New code
function checkAuthAndRun(func) {
  if (authenticated) {
    func();
  } else {
    console.log("User is not allowed to do this");
  }
}

// Calling your functions
checkAuthAndRun(thing1);
checkAuthAndRun(thing2);
checkAuthAndRun(thing3);
```

Example with parameters

```js
// Some mock up of you existing code
var authenticated = true;

function thing1() {alert(1); }
function thing2(a) { alert(a); }
function thing3(a, b) { alert(a + b); }

// New code
function checkAuthAndRun(func) {
  if (authenticated) {
    // This line will need to have as many arguments[x] parameters as the function
    // with the most parameters that you will call through this method
    func(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
  } else {
    console.log("User is not allowed to do this");
  }
}

// Calling your functions
checkAuthAndRun(thing1);
checkAuthAndRun(thing2, "Parameter 1");
checkAuthAndRun(thing3, "Parameter 1", "Parameter 2");
```

Comment: Hi, what if those functions has also parameters? Because if I use this technique first function will run and then it will check this condition and run again right?

Comment: @Kadir If the function have parameters, you can also pass those into the check. I will add an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply @DBS. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use && to short-circuit the statement.

Like, `condition && fun()` , fun() will be called only when conditon is true.

This is how && operator works in JS. if the first expression is wrong then it won't execute the rest of them otherwise it returns the value returned by the following expression(s), of course after executing them.

```js
function auth(condition) {
 return condition;
}

function isOdd(n) {
 console.log(n," is odd ",n %2 == 0);
}

auth(false) && isOdd(3); //won't call
auth(false) && isOdd(4); //won't call
auth(true) && isOdd(5);
auth(true) && isOdd(6);
```

Comment: While this is technically shorter, I would argue that it's not worth the loss of readability.

Comment: @DBS: Maybe you are right. But I use this a lot hence answered. I guess if you know how its work then its quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem then I guess you don't want `if-else` or `switch` to clutter your code and you want a cleaner way to do this. What I would've done is, made a configuration file and executed it in the following way:

```
import {function1, function2, function3, function4 ...} from './functions';

const FUNCTIONS_TO_RUN = {
   auth: () => {
      function1();
      function2();
      ...
   },
   noAuth: () => {
      function3();
      function4();
      ...
   },
   ....
};
```

while calling them, I would just do as :

```
FUNCTIONS_TO_RUN[conditionType]();
```

This is not the exact solution but an idea how you can implement it in a cleaner way.

`conditionType` can be `auth` or `noAuth` in this case.